# Need assistance in VBA XMLHTTP code for getting complete page load or any waiting mechanism

Tags: excel, vba, xmlhttprequest

Hi have written below code to get entire page load using VBA's XMLHTTP method but every time i am getting partial loaded data.

### I only want completed to get page detail after once it completely load and i only want this through xmlhttp not through internet explorer classes. so i tried all wait mechanism but its not working. .

```
Option Explicit
Sub showXML()
    Dim xmlpage As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim url As String

    url = "http://www.the-stockmarket.com/product/Moen-MO100429-Repair-Kit-35549?Ns=Primary_Finish%7C1%7C%7CSort_Order%7C1&amp;No=26796&amp;N=3000556+3000571+3000557+3000558+3000559+3000560+3000561+3000562+3000563+3000564+3000565+3000566"

    xmlpage.Open "GET", url, False
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:20"))
    xmlpage.send

    With xmlpage

        While Not .readyState = 4                '<---------- wait
            Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")
        Wend

        If .Status = 200 Then
            While InStr(1, .responseText, "Retrieving ...", 0) > 0 '<---------- wait again
                Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")
            Wend
        End If
    End With

    Dim myfile As String
    myfile = "D:\test1.txt"

    Open myfile For Output As #11

    Write #11, xmlpage.responseText

    Close #11
End Sub
```

I need complete loaded page data. Currently i am getting data with text "Retrieving ..." but in completed loaded data i would receive some number there.

Comment: what's the url?

Comment: Thanks, I have updated code with URL.. still i have put that url below. Looking forward any assistance from you soon. 
http://www.the-stockmarket.com/product/Moen-MO100429-Repair-Kit-35549?Ns=Primary_Finish%7C1%7C%7CSort_Order%7C1&amp;No=26796&amp;N=3000556+3000571+3000557+3000558+3000559+3000560+3000561+3000562+3000563+3000564+3000565+3000566

Comment: Hi anybody have any solution for above problem?

Comment: What info do you want from that page?

Comment: All embedded product quantities specially that come little bit after page load .. means it took time after loading page.. my above code related to xmlhttp only shows "Retrieving .." text that appears while quantities were loading... So my code fetch data just before coming those quantities.. this code should wait until page completely load... Thanks

Comment: Example quantity?

Comment: Hi sorry for being late.. the value right after the word "Quantity Available:" like 783,20,40,19 etc, further i have left a URL wherein i have highlighted the quantity part... https://imgur.com/sJJCYzX

Comment: Hi QHarr, did you get a chance to check code.

Comment: I will have a look later today

Comment: I had a look and I suspect that they deliberately hinder web-scraping as I can issue POST requests that page makes but I am not giving the same content the browser gets in response. The requests are successful but different content is returned to me. An interesting situation.

Comment: Okay will have to check that as well actually, i can get the entire data using internet explorer classes and libraries including the part that run after page load but unable to get the same using xml http library..   need more digging or have to move in python.. might be it could work.. but i have somewhere feeling that xml http could do that... You plz try here i am too checking.. thanks for time..

Comment: On digging into the question I found it a very interesting one once I observed the results. I even tried adding the item to the cart via xmlhttp. Instead of getting what the browser showed as expected response, I simply got "added to cart" as response.

Comment: I think if the question could be phrased around that behaviour and for a decent explanation of either how to get the desired number or an explanation for why we get the result we do, it is worth a bounty I am happy to put on.

Comment: For example, see this: https://pastebin.com/gtcVUd9Z and compare against what browser gets for same action of adding 1 item to cart.

Comment: Hi  QHarr, i tried your codes but these are only adding items to cart but i want the quantity to be extract into excel

Comment: Yes I know. Look at my previous comment. It was to backup the assertion about unusual behaviour of requests. In both cases we don’t get the same response via code as browser.

Comment: could you please suggest about that as well?